# How to integrate the panel with GNOME Themes in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, themes, panel, customization, gnome-shell

I'm loving the look and feel in GNOME from Ubuntu 17.10, but at the moment of installing GNOME Tweaks and installing a theme (in my case Arc Theme) some things still have the Adwaita colors, with the Panel feeling really odd with the brown gradient, vs. the flat appearence of the Arc Theme.

I would like to more fully integrate the theme with this new version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Top bar style is controlled by GNOME shell theme. You may use *(GNOME) Tweaks* to change it.

First install Tweaks by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Open Tweaks and go to *Appearance* section. Under *Themes* you'll be able to select an installed shell theme:

[image]

**Important note:** You won't be able to select any shell theme installed in your home directory by default. For that you'll have install and activate [User Themes](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/) shell extension first.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, was exactly was I was looking for